# Function becoming object

Tags: javascript

I've got the following simple code:

```
   someFields.forEach(
       function (itemId) {window.opener.Xrm.Page.getControl(itemId).setDisabled(true);});
```

forEach is implemented as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (we have to support ie8+).

The problem is with this part:

```
  if ({}.toString.call(callback) !== "[object Function]") {
      throw new TypeError( callback + " is not a function" );
    }
```

The browser (IE9 in IE7 compatibility mode) identifies my callback as [object Object] instead of [object Function]. However the object has the call method, and function works just fine if I remove this check. 

Can anyone clarify why I see such behavior?

Comment: JOOI, why are you running in IE7 compatibility mode when you only have to support IE8+?

Comment: Won't `.call(callback)` return the return value of `callback` instead of `callback` itself? Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can play with?

Comment: @sp00m: No, it will return the return value of the call to the `{}.toString` function

Comment: Something that could affect this test is the fact you're running compat mode. Compatibility mode is not an accurate representation. If you want to see the exact behavior with IE7, you would need to install IE7.

Comment: Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYLy8/) reproduce your issue? IE10 in IE7 compatibility mode prints `[object Function]` as expected...

Comment: Though your example should work but can you check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Jjs6h/)?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha, I've slightly modified your example, and here's what I've got
>> !!(fn && fn.constructor && fn.call && fn.apply) 
true 
>> Object.prototype.toString.call(fn) == '[object Function]' false

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on the toString method to detect the type of an instance. This aproach is unreliable even in the context of a Java 7 vm and the standard base object class there. The return value depends on the vendor of the vm.

Generally, toString is never predictable unless you own and maintain the API. Don't ever parse it or compare it to derive logic.

...use Modernizr to detect the browser